# Docker desktop (Windows 10 Pro) — Why is there no Advanced tab in Settings->Resources?

Tags: docker, windows-10, docker-desktop

[image]

Why is there no Advanced tab in Settings->Resources?

Comment: What do you want to set or modify?

Comment: I want to change images directory.

Comment: And to see this tab (◣_◢)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you run docker desktop with the new WSL 2 backend and enable `Use the WSL 2 based engine` in Settings/General :
[show settings/general](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vhgI.png)

when you want to modify config settings for WSL 2 to explicitly limit the available resources you can do that by creating a .wslconfig file inside your user profile directory

Open Windows Terminal/CMD/PowerShell and run the commands below:

```
# turn off all wsl instances such as docker-desktop
wsl -- shutdown

notepad "$env:USERPROFILE/.wslconfig"
```

then add this items in .wslconfig file :

```
[wsl2]
kernel=<path>              # An absolute Windows path to a custom Linux kernel.
memory=<size>              # How much memory to assign to the WSL2 VM.
processors=<number>        # How many processors to assign to the WSL2 VM.
swap=<size>                # How much swap space to add to the WSL2 VM. 0 for no swap file.
swapFile=<path>            # An absolute Windows path to the swap vhd.
localhostForwarding=<bool> # Boolean specifying if ports bound to wildcard or localhost in the WSL2 VM should be connectable from the host via localhost:port (default true).

# <path> entries must be absolute Windows paths with escaped backslashes, for example C:\\Users\\adamc\\kernel
# <size> entries must be size followed by unit, for example 8GB or 512MB
```

For Example :

```
[wsl2]
memory=2GB            
processors=4
```

Then Save the file and restart the docker-desktop service.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me, for whatever reason. Despite following your instructions, the vmmem.exe process always uses 1Gb of memory.

I set the memory=768MB

Comment: Same for me, my wsl is being recognize as file WSLCONFIG but my vmmem take 100% of my memory

Answer (score 25):

Are you running with WSL 2 integration? It would appear the bulk of the settings don't apply in that scenario, and the 'Advanced' tab is removed. (See https://admcpr.com/running-docker-desktop-with-the-new-wsl-2-backend/ ).

Comment: how to remove WSL2 integrations?

Comment: @LizardDerad I disable it in the General tab "Use the WSL 2 based engine" option and the Advanced tab is showed under Resources

Answer (score -7):

You can add or modify image information in `Docker Engine`